# Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Hourly>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Hourly>') to type '[Hourly]'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've API response like this:

[image: API Response]

Here **hourly** list has 48 items. So I want to slice this array after decoding this response from JSON:

```
if !self.HourlyData.isEmpty {
            self.HourlyData = self.HourlyData[0...23]
}
```

But this gives error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Hourly>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Hourly>') to type '[Hourly]'
```

Then tried this:

```
if !self.HourlyData.isEmpty {
            self.HourlyData = self.HourlyData.index(before: 24)
}
```

Still got this erorr:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type '[Hourly]'
```

So, how can I slice the first 24 items from this **hourly** list.

Comment: Change your variable type declaration to `ArraySlice<Hourly>` instead of Array. btw you can simply get `yourCollection.prefix(24)`

Comment: And you should lowercase `HourlyData` -> `hourlyData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
self.HourlyData = Array(self.HourlyData[0...23])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of convention, it's bad practice to capitalize first letter for variable.

```
self.hourly = Array(self.hourly.prefix(24))
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix